# How to replace non ascii characters in pyspark dataframe

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, non-ascii-characters

is there any function in pyspark that works the same way as replace_non_ascii in R (package textclean)? I have a dataframe in pyspark with few columns that contains accents. I want to replace the accents with characters. for example,

```
name        name_without_accents
inšećt      insect
hügo        hugo
åvendaño    avendano
```

Any help? TIA.

Comment: how did you solve this issue? I am facing the same issue.